# Why does function equals return error in Java

Tags: java, object

I have a class Objekt in java in that class I wrote a function to check objects the serial number of objects from other classes and I keep getting .equals error. I was wondering is it because I wrote String function and the serial number(Evidenca) is int or I wrote something wrong. So any ideas are welcome.

```
boolean obstaja = false;
    for(PoslovniProstor pp : this.PoslovniProstori)
    {
        if(pp.getEvidenca().equals(poslovniProstor.getEvidenca()))
        {
            obstaja = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

This colors .equals in red bare in mind that the class I am taking an object from is PoslovniProstor and I created an ArrayList in this class Objekt and is called PoslovniProstori

```
public ArrayList<PoslovniProstor> getPoslovniProstori(){
    return this.PoslovniProstori;
}
```

So yea any help is welcome. :D

Comment: And what's the type of the value returned by `getEvidenca()`? Probably some primitive type. Primitives are compared using `==`, objects are compared using `equals()`.

Comment: you wrote "serial number(Evidenca) is int". `int`doesn't have an `equals` method. Use `==` instead

Comment: Every now and then we are reminded how odd and inconsistent some aspects of Java are!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`equals` method and `==`  operator have separate use cases. In short, `equals` is used to check for equality of value whether `==` is used to check for same reference.
In your case, as you have said `Evidenca` is int, then, to compare one `int` to another `int` use `==` operator.

For more details, you can check this thread [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/5332914)

Answer (score 0):

As int is a primitive type, it has to be compared using == rather than .equals().